# Image blocking issue generated mail

Tags: html, image, email

We are sending mail using Java API and HTML template like

```
    <html>
<head>
 <title>Activation Mail</title>
 <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body style="margin-left: 0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;background-color: #F0F0F0;">
  <img src="http://uat-flipxl.fliplabs.net/flipxl/style_appl/images/banner1.jpg" style="width:620px;height:95px;"/>

</body>
</html>
```

The mail successfully sent. But image is not displayed in mail. In mail image source is created as

```
<img src="//www.rediffmail.com/cgi-bin/red.cgi?red=http%3A%2F%2Fuat%2Dflipxl%2Efliplabs%2Enet%2Fflipxl%2Fstyle%5Fappl%2Fimages%2Fbanner1%2Ejpg&amp;isImage=1&amp;BlockImage=1&amp;rediffng=0&amp;rogue=c0f0aa43da2e831f97528cd4d35ab6eac85bfe9f" style="width:620px;height:95px;">
```

So image is not displayed.How can I override this problem? Any solution please.

Comment: Please be more specific, you can put some error's here in this case it will help to solve your question. And try to explain better what you want.

Comment: Maybe the source of the problem is the mail server (either sending one or retrieving one) is replacing this due to configuration.